# how to update a label on a d3 line graph?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to have a label on the end of each line and i am having all the label on one place instead. It is not even updating the label but creating a new one next to it.

this is how i am adding a lable:

```
   linesGroup.append("g")
      .style("font-size","12px")
      .append("text")

      .datum(function(d) {return linedata.points[0] ; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +       y(d.rate) + ")"; 
         })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d){return (d.tag+"-"+d.rate);});
```

This is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/GsaGb/9/

Comment: You're always `append`ing new labels. You need to use the existing ones instead.

Comment: You can also just delete the old labels before you create the new one, but you'd need some way of identifying the elements you wanted to remove, like giving your <g> a class of "temporaryLabel" and then d3.selectAll("g.temporaryLabel").remove() just before you append the new one(s).

Comment: i am not even getting the label in the right place

Comment: when i remove it i am getting an undefined label!!

Comment: this is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/GsaGb/11/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined label because inside `redrawwithoutanimation` function, you are adding new points but not creating a tag property in the new points:

```
    var new_point = {
        rate: removedPoint.rate,
        created_at: lastpoint.created_at + 6000,
        tag: removedPoint.tag
    };
```

see that I added `tag:removedPoint.tag` and this should fix the undefined issue.

And, to get the label after each line you will have to use `enter()` and `data()`

```
linesGroup.selectAll("g.line-label").data(chart_data).enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "line-label")
        .style("font-size", "12px")
        .append("text")
        .datum(function (d) {
          return d.points[0];
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
          return "translate(" + x.range()[1] + "," + y(d.rate) + ")";
        })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) {
        return (d.tag + "-" + d.rate);
    });
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsaGb/12/)